# Get selected text from a drop-down menu (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu

Im already getting the value and using it to add an total item price
is it possible to get the selected text from a drop down menu and add it to an array list?

Here is how im creating my MenuItems from firestore.

```
  final itemExtras = snap.data.documents[i]['op'];
                                      for (var extra in itemExtras) {
                                        if (extra['add'] > 0) {
                                          items.add(
                                            DropdownMenuItem(
                                              child: Text(
                                                extra['name'] +
                                                    ' + Bs. ' +
                                                    extra['add']
                                                        .toString(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                              value: extra['add'],
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }
```

and this is the button

```
DropdownButton(
                                              isExpanded: true,
                                              items: items,
                                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .textTheme
                                                  .title,
                                              onChanged: (selectedValue) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  dropdownValues[i] =
                                                      selectedValue;
                                                  addPrice =
                                                      dropdownValues.fold(
                                                          0,
                                                          (previous,
                                                                  current) =>
                                                              previous +
                                                              current);
                                                  total = (addPrice +=
                                                      widget.snapshot[
                                                          'price']);
                                                });
                                                print(dropdownValues
                                                        .toString() +
                                                    index.data.toString());
                                              },
                                              hint: Text('Select Extra'),
                                              value: dropdownValues[i],
                                            )
```

i need to get the extra['name']

Answer (score 0):

change your `DropdownMenuItem.value` to `extra`, not `extra['add']`, then it will be `selectedValue`'s value.

Comment: `The following assertion was thrown building:
flutter: There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 0.
flutter: Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
flutter: Failed assertion: line 834 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
flutter:               items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
flutter:                 return item.value == value;
flutter:               }).length == 1'
flutter:`